# Generate wrapper to any dll with help of macros/templates

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, c++17, c++14

For example I have `name1.dll` with methods:

- `void func1(int)`
- `int func2(bool, char)`

and `name2.dll` with methods:

- `std::string func1()`
- `bool func2(int, int, int)`

To work with them, I want to get some generated classes and their objects, respectively, using the following syntax

```
DECLARE_WRAPPER(
    Wrapper1,
    DECLARE_METHOD(func1, void(int))
    DECLARE_METHOD(func2, int(bool, char))
)
```

And

```
DECLARE_WRAPPER(
    Wrapper2,
    DECLARE_METHOD(func1, std::string())
    DECLARE_METHOD(func2, bool(int, int, int))
)
```

and use like this:

```
Wrapper1 w1("name1.dll");
w1 func1(6);
w1.func2(false, 'c');

Wrapper w2("name2.dll");
w2.func1();
w2.func2(6, 5, 7)
```

My C++ code so far for this purpose following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

#define DECLARE_METHOD(name, ret, ...) \
    ret name(__VA_ARGS__) { \
        FARPROC proc = GetProcAddress(m_hDll, #name); \
        if (proc == nullptr) { \
            throw std::runtime_error("Function not found"); \
        } \
        va_list args; \
        va_start(args, __VA_ARGS__); \
        ret result = reinterpret_cast<ret(__cdecl*)(__VA_ARGS__)>(proc)(__VA_ARGS__); \
        va_end(args); \
        return result; \
    }

#define DECLARE_WRAPPER(wrapperName, ...) \
    class wrapperName { \
    public: \
        wrapperName(const std::string& dllPath) : m_hDll(nullptr) { \
            m_hDll = LoadLibraryA(dllPath.c_str()); \
        } \
        ~wrapperName() { \
            if (m_hDll) { \
                FreeLibrary(m_hDll); \
            } \
        } \
        __VA_ARGS__ \
    private: \
        HMODULE m_hDll; \
    };

DECLARE_WRAPPER(
Wrapper1,
DECLARE_METHOD(func1, void, int)
DECLARE_METHOD(func2, int, bool, char)
);

DECLARE_WRAPPER(
Wrapper2,
DECLARE_METHOD(func1, std::string)
DECLARE_METHOD(func2, bool, int, int, int)
);

int main() {
    const std::string dllPath1 = "name1.dll";
    const std::string dllPath2 = "name2.dll";

    Wrapper1 w1(dllPath1);
    w1.func1(6);
    int res = w1.func2(false, 'c');
    std::cout << "Wrapper1::func2 returned " << res << std::endl;

    Wrapper2 w2(dllPath2);
    std::string str = w2.func1();
    std::cout << "Wrapper2::func1 returned " << str << std::endl;
    bool b = w2.func2(6, 5, 7);
    std::cout << "Wrapper2::func2 returned " << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I have errors, and I can't make it work. How can this code be fixed? Or, am I trying to achieve something that can't be done in C++? Current version I can use is `C++17`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use `DECLARE_METHOD()` *inside* of `DECLARE_WRAPPER()` the way you are doing. You will likely have to break up `DECLARE_WRAPPER()` into separate macros so you can then use `DECLARE_METHOD()`s in between them.

However, `DECLARE_METHOD()` itself will certainly not work the way you have written it. It canont use `__VA_ARGS__` to both declare the method parameters and to call the loaded `proc()`. And, it cannot pass `__VA_ARGS__` to `va_start()` at all (not that it matters since you are not using `args` anyway). You should use C++-style variadic templates instead of C-style variadic macros.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#define DECLARE_METHOD(name, returnType) \
    template<typename... Args> \
    returnType name(Args&&... args) \
    { \
        using procType = returnType (__cdecl *)(Args...); \
        procType proc = reinterpret_cast<procType>(GetProcAddress(m_hDll, #name)); \
        if (proc == nullptr) { \
            throw std::runtime_error("Function not found"); \
        } \
        return proc(std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
    }

#define DECLARE_WRAPPER_BEGIN(wrapperName) \
    class wrapperName { \
    public: \
        wrapperName(const std::string& dllPath) : m_hDll(nullptr) { \
            m_hDll = LoadLibraryA(dllPath.c_str()); \
            if (m_hDll == nullptr) \
                throw std::runtime_error("DLL not found"); \
        } \
        ~wrapperName() { \
            FreeLibrary(m_hDll); \
        }

#define DECLARE_WRAPPER_END() \
    private: \
        HMODULE m_hDll; \
    };

DECLARE_WRAPPER_BEGIN(Wrapper1)
DECLARE_METHOD(func1, void)
DECLARE_METHOD(func2, int)
DECLARE_WRAPPER_END()

DECLARE_WRAPPER_BEGIN(Wrapper2)
DECLARE_METHOD(func1, std::string)
DECLARE_METHOD(func2, bool)
DECLARE_WRAPPER_END()
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/p0XUo0)

---

On a side note, it is not safe for `Wrapper2::func1()` to pass a `std::string` across the DLL boundary.  If the DLL function returns a `char*` that you want converted into a `std::string`, then your `DECLARE_METHOD()` macro will have to account for that, by having separate parameters to specify the two return types individually.  For example:

```
#define DECLARE_METHOD(name, dllReturnType, methReturnType) \
    template<typename... Args> \
    methReturnType name(Args&&... args) \
    { \
        using procType = dllReturnType (__cdecl *)(Args...); \
        procType proc = reinterpret_cast<procType>(GetProcAddress(m_hDll, #name)); \
        if (proc == nullptr) { \
            throw std::runtime_error("Function not found"); \
        } \
        return proc(std::forward<Args>(args)...); \
    }
}

DECLARE_WRAPPER_BEGIN(Wrapper1)
DECLARE_METHOD(func1, void, void)
DECLARE_METHOD(func2, int, int)
DECLARE_WRAPPER_END()

DECLARE_WRAPPER_BEGIN(Wrapper2)
DECLARE_METHOD(func1, char*, std::string)
DECLARE_METHOD(func2, bool, bool)
DECLARE_WRAPPER_END()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you, please, tell me one more thing: is there any way to modify your code for adding ability of "highlighting" needed parameters when using function call? Or at least checking passed parameters count at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful for somebody, so I'm writing my "final" form. Yes, there are a lot of things to do, but here is the skeleton that almost suits my fits:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <type_traits>
#include <filesystem>


#define DECLARE_METHOD(name, ret, ...)                 \
    private:                                           \
        using MethodType_##name = ret(*)(__VA_ARGS__); \
        MethodType_##name m_##name{ nullptr };         \


#define DEFINE_METHOD(name)                                                                                   \
    public:                                                                                                   \
        template<typename... Args>                                                                            \
        typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(m_##name), Args...>>::value,      \
                                std::invoke_result_t<decltype(m_##name), Args...>>::type                      \
        name(Args&&... args)                                                                                  \
        {                                                                                                     \
            if (!m_##name)                                                                                    \
            {                                                                                                 \
                m_##name = reinterpret_cast<MethodType_##name>(GetProcAddress(m_hDll, #name));                \
            }                                                                                                 \
            if (!m_##name)                                                                                    \
            {                                                                                                 \
                throw std::runtime_error("Function not found");                                               \
            }                                                                                                 \
            return m_##name(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                                                     \
        }                                                                                                     \
                                                                                                              \
        template<typename... Args>                                                                            \
        typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(m_##name), Args...>>::value>::type \
        name(Args&&... args)                                                                                  \
        {                                                                                                     \
            if (!m_##name)                                                                                    \
            {                                                                                                 \
                m_##name = reinterpret_cast<MethodType_##name>(GetProcAddress(m_hDll, #name));                \
            }                                                                                                 \
            if (!m_##name)                                                                                    \
            {                                                                                                 \
                throw std::runtime_error("Function not found");                                               \
            }                                                                                                 \
            m_##name(std::forward<Args>(args)...);                                                            \
        }


#define DECLARE_DLL_WRAPPER(WrapperName, ...)                            \
    class WrapperName                                                    \
    {                                                                    \
    public:                                                              \
        explicit WrapperName(const std::filesystem::path& fullPathToDll) \
        {                                                                \
            m_hDll = LoadLibraryA(fullPathToDll.u8string().c_str());     \
            if (!m_hDll)                                                 \
            {                                                            \
                throw std::runtime_error("DLL not found");               \
            }                                                            \
        }                                                                \
        ~WrapperName()                                                   \
        {                                                                \
            FreeLibrary(m_hDll);                                         \
        }                                                                \
        __VA_ARGS__                                                      \
                                                                         \
    private:                                                             \
        HMODULE m_hDll{ nullptr };                                       \
};


#define DECLARE_AND_DEFINE_METHOD(name, ret, ...)   \
    DECLARE_METHOD(name, ret, __VA_ARGS__)          \
    DEFINE_METHOD(name)


// Declaring some dll wrapper type for futher using it
DECLARE_DLL_WRAPPER(Wrapper1,
    DECLARE_AND_DEFINE_METHOD(func1, int, bool bParam, int iParam)
    DECLARE_AND_DEFINE_METHOD(func2, void, float dParam)
)


int main()
{
    Wrapper1 w1("plugin.dll");

    const auto ret = w1.func1(false, 6);
    w1.func2(2.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

Do not judge strictly. Ideally, it would be very convenient and good if it were possibility to highlight all the parameters of the method used.

Comment: Unless you explain what changed, and *why*, this isn't very useful.